# how to generate X-Amzn-Trace-Id for Golang in the simplest way

Tags: go, sdk, generator, aws-xray, open-telemetry

I have been seeing this [documentation by AWS](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/opensource/go-support-for-aws-x-ray-now-available-in-aws-distro-for-opentelemetry/)

Is there any simple way to generate "X-Amzn-Trace-Id" with X-Ray?
the `func NewIDGenerator()` doesn't produce the format of `Root xxx`.

or can we just use a trusted library for it? Thank you

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't produce the format of Root xxx"?

Comment: @SrikanthChekuri it should look like this `X-Amzn-Trace-Id: Root=1-67891233-abcdef012345678912345678` from this doc
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/application/load-balancer-request-tracing.html

Comment: That is context propagation not id generation. Are you looking for how to generate ids or propagate context?

Comment: i am looking for something to generate an "X-Amzn-Trace-Id". cmiiw it could be produce by generating a Trace Id first, then propagate it? @SrikanthChekuri

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First Create a Trace using OpenTelemetry's tracer and then inject that context to XRAY Propagator to get TraceId as per AWS's ID specification.

```golang
func GetAmazonTraceId(ctx context.Context) string {
    propogator := xray.Propagator{}
    carrier := propagation.HeaderCarrier{}
    propogator.Inject(ctx, carrier)
    traceId := carrier.Get("X-Amzn-Trace-Id")
    return traceId
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Or, you can write your code to convert standard trace id(String) to xray trace id.

```
private static final String TRACE_ID_VERSION = "1";
private static final char TRACE_ID_DELIMITER = '-';
private static final int TRACE_ID_DELIMITER_INDEX_1 = 1;
private static final int TRACE_ID_DELIMITER_INDEX_2 = 10;
private static final int TRACE_ID_FIRST_PART_LENGTH = 8;

public static String toXRayTraceId(String traceId) {
    return TRACE_ID_VERSION
        + TRACE_ID_DELIMITER
        + traceId.substring(0, TRACE_ID_FIRST_PART_LENGTH)
        + TRACE_ID_DELIMITER
        + traceId.substring(TRACE_ID_FIRST_PART_LENGTH);
  }
```